# AOP pointcut expression exclude java.lang.Object.*(..)?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

Found in following leagacy code the expression

```
<aop:config>
    <!--   the execution of any method defined in the 'service' package or a sub-package --> 
    <aop:pointcut id="apiServicesPointCuts"
    expression="execution(* my.example.api..service..*.*(..)) &amp;&amp; !execution(* java.lang.Object.*(..))" />

    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="apiServicesPointCuts" />
</aop:config>
```

the expression

```
!execution(* java.lang.Object.*(..)
```

If I read it correct that means do not match advice on any method withhin the java.lang.Object.
Does that make sense when the advice is for a transaction manager?

I'm using aspectj 1.6.8

Comment: i really do not understand what the question is.

Comment: does not make any sense to me, probably you could remove that part of the pointcut...especially if you are not using load time weaving

Comment: makes a lot of sense to me, keep it. toString/equals/notify(All)/wait/hashCode/getClass are probably not the targets of a service interceptor. then again, you could just figure out what the code does.